# Newsletter option in contact us in magento

Tags: magento

How can I add checkbox functionality when it checked email of contact us form subscribe to the newsletter?

Comment: overload Mage_Contacts_IndexController
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

and put these line in postAction function

 if($post['is_subscribed'] == 1){
                    $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($post['email']);
                }

Answer (score 0):

Edit the contact form and add in your own checkbox, and then modify the contacts controller using the method above (Mage_Contacts_IndexController)

You would then add in some code to subscribe to the newsletter using the email address from the posted form:

```
$status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
       ->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
}
else {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
        ->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
}
```